# Oracle Lite help for developing on Windows Mobile

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Can anybody help me with Oracle Lite for use with Windows Mobile 6.5? I couldn't even get my self started with it. I tried to read the documentation provided with it but it only shows me Oracle Lite's features and there is not even a What-to-do or How-to-do part on Oracle documentations. It may have samples but how do I use these samples?

I've installed Oracle Lite to my PC and I'm not even sure if I've installed it correctly. As I do not know what to do next. I'm an intermmediate developer using MySQL and SQL Server before. Any tutorial link would do or a book or maybe an answer here step by step would be gladly appreciated. As again, Oracle docs are so unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that Oracle Lite is not being actively developed.

For the Lite Client Database, the recommended replacement product is Berkeley DB
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index-085366.html

For sync and device management, the recommended replacement product is Database Mobile Server
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html

Eric Jensen,
Oracle Product Manager